# Multiple ip addresses in single string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have that kind of datas :

```
172.12.1.3;185.16.6.13;...
```

And sometimes the submask so it could be :

```
172.12.1.3;185.16.6.13/32;172.12.1.4;...
```

So I wanted to use regex (in js) to be sure each ip address is correct using ";" as separator.

It should not be too difficult, but even with a few research i've just manage to do something like this :

`/^(((^|\.?)(1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){4}(\;|$))*$/`

Btw I know that I should, but I'm not really into regex...

Can someone give me a hand please ?

edit :

So i've tried something like this :

```
var poolIp = v.split(";");

var ipAddress = /^(((^|\.?)(1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){4}(\;|$))*$/;
var ret = true;
for (var i = 0; i < poolIp.length; i++) {
    var matches = ipAddress.exec(poolIp[i]);
    if (!matches) {
        ret = false;
    }
}
return ret;
```

And it's way better, but ip address with submask is not valid and ip with 3 digits are valid.

Comment: Why not split based on `;` first and then check each value?. Would make your life a little easier

Comment: I've tried, but that wasn't a true success.
I'll try something new based on what you suggest and give you the result.

Comment: please format your code snippets yourself in future. go there to see what i changed: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41011362/revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following function to validate such strings of IP addresses. Note that the port number validation can be enhanced, I just check if the value is numeric.

```js
function checkIsIPV4s(entry) {
  var ips = entry.split(';');       // Split into separate IPs
  for (var ip of ips) {
    var blocks = ip.split(/[.\/]/); // Split with dot and slash
    if(blocks.length === 5) {       // If there are 5 blocks,
      var last = blocks.pop();      //   remove the last one 
      if (!/^\d+$/.test(last)) {    //   and check if it is numeric
        return false;               //   if not - FALSE
      }
    }
    if(blocks.length === 4) {       // If block number is 4
      var res = blocks.every(function(block) { // check each part
        return parseInt(block,10) >=0 && parseInt(block,10) <= 255;
      });
      if (!res) {return false; }    // If any part is not in 0..255 - FALSE
    } else {  
      return false;                 // If block number is not 4 - FALSE
    }
  }
  return true;
}
var str = "172.12.1.3;185.16.6.13/32;172.12.1.4;255.255.255.255";
console.log(checkIsIPV4s(str));
str2 = "172.12.1.34444;185.16.6.13/32";
console.log(checkIsIPV4s(str2));
```

However, there is a way to use a huge and unreadable regex, too. Adding this just to show that it is possible to do it with a regex:

```
/^(?:(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.){3}(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))(?:\/\d+)?(?:;(?:(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.){3}(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))(?:\/\d+)?)*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1ypa48/1)

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.){3}(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))(?:\/\d+)?` - a single IP pattern (all up to `(?:\/\d+)?`) with an optional port number (`(?:\/\d+)?`)
- `(?:` - the non-capturing group start

  - `;` - the separator
  - `(?:(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.){3}(?:\d{1,2}|1\d{2}|2(?:[0-4]\d|5[0-5]))(?:\/\d+)?` - the single IP pattern, same as above
- `)*` - 0 or more occurrences of the non-capturing group sequences
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var re = /^(;?[1-9][\d]{1,2}(\.[\d]{1,3}){3}(\/[\d]{1,3})?)+$/
re.test('172.12.1.3;185.16.6.13/32;172.12.1.4') // true
re.test('172.12.1.3;185.16.6.13/32;172.12.1') // false
re.test('072.12.1.3;185.16.6.13/32;172.12.1.4') // false
```

Or splitting them up:

```
var re = /^[1-9][\d]{1,2}(\.[\d]{1,3}){3}(\/[\d]{1,3})?$/
var ip1 = '172.12.1.3;185.16.6.13/32;172.12.1.4'.split(';');
var ip2 = '172.12.1.3;185.16.6.13/32;172.12.1'.split(';');
var ip3 = '072.12.1.3;185.16.6.13/32;172.12.1.4'.split(';');
ip1.every((ip) => re.test(ip));
ip2.every((ip) => re.test(ip));
ip3.every((ip) => re.test(ip));
```

You can use http://regexr.com/ to test your regexp, and read about [Array.every here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)